# How to homogenize the brightness in a photomicrograph image

Tags: image-processing

I have a good image about my sample:

[image]

But as you see,there is a problem in this picture that is the illumination is not balance. How to use *Mathematica* to improve it?

Comment: Have you seen "[Detecting and correcting gradational brightness variations in a grayscale image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30823)"?